# Where can I find data sets for machine monitoring?

Tags: data-request, time-series

Can anyone point me to time series data in the domain of machine monitoring/condition monitoring (for example, vibration analysis data)?

Answer (score 2):

With some clever thinking you can find anything.

I searched '[vibration data filetype:csv](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=vibration%20data%20filetype%3acsv)'.

In the results was some very complete data set: [see here for example](http://www.tepco.co.jp/en/nu/fukushima-np/plant-data/f1_6_Katogenshotsuika1-05.csv)

Answer (score 1):

I would go to statistical analysis software documentation (like the SAS/QC product, or the R quality contral task view) and look at the data sets used as examples for the particular type of machine condition/monitoring application you're looking for

SAS/QC:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/qc/indexproc.html#qc132

check out monitoring (shewhart charts, MVP procedures) and reliability procedures.

In R, check out the survival task view:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html

(survival analysis is the parent area of reliability, you use the same machinery to think about survival of a patient with cancer X as you do for an alternator with coil type Y).

For monitoring in R, the packages are not so well organized, but SPC, QCC
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spc/
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qcc/

should help.